# Problem about installing opencv library to raspberry pi 4 by ssh

Tags: python, opencv, terminal, raspberry-pi, facial-identification

I'm currently trying to install the OpenCV library to raspberry pi 4 by using the ssh and command line, but I couldn't accomplish it.

I tried pip install, make -j command and even the source code but I couldn't install the library. When I use make -j command it gives me this error:

```
 [ 62%] Built target opencv_dnn make:[Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

I tried most of the solutions and also the tutorials of PyImageSearch but still couldn't install the library. I'm currently using **Raspbian Buster** from July 2019, what should I do?

Comment: show more lines from error. There should be information what makes problem. Maybe it need some tool or libraries to compile it

Comment: `pip install opencv-python-aarch64` try this

Comment: thank you all for your interests, I solved my problem by changing my cmake lines but nevertheless I thank all of you...

Comment: @kaanutku can you share your answer with us